# PHP-FPM + Apache - performance?

Tags: php, apache, performance, centos7

I have strange problem with server - PHP-FPM 7.0 with Apache2.4 on CentOS

Server spec:

Load Balancer

2x 4CPU, 7Gb Ram CentOS

FPM config:

```
[apache_prod]
user = apache_prod
group = apache
listen = /var/run/php-fpm/apache_prod.sock
listen.owner = apache_prod
listen.group = apache
listen.mode = 0660
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 450
pm.start_servers = 20
pm.min_spare_servers = 10
pm.max_spare_servers = 20
pm.status_path = /status_prod
pm.max_requests = 1000
```

CPU and RAM are used in about 30%, but requests after 10 minutes of work take long time [around 30-50 sec and longer] and load average go to cosmos.

Any sugestion what I make wrong ? 
Or mayby the problem is in other place?

Comment: any reason why you singled out FPM as the heavy consumer ?  DB ? connection pool ? memcached ? other pieces of the robot could all create race/lock conditions.

Comment: I figured out that bottleneck is App cache on slow disk.
When I change id to SSD - the problem with requests time gone.

But the CPU and RAM still in 30% and fpm yells about increasing the pm.starts_server or max/min spare.